# Limiting the size of JSON post request in Tomcat 8

Tags: json, tomcat

I have tried to limit the post request size of api by setting **maxpostsize** in /conf/server.xml, but its not working,

Is there is any way to limit the size of json request in Tomcat?

this is my server.xml connector config

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" 
               maxPostSize="30000" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your `server.xml` file?

Comment: I have added the server.xml part that i changed @Ortomala Lokni

Comment: How do you test that the maxPostSize is not taken into account?

Comment: I have used api request with different JSON size, but even up to 10 MB json is got success response, its not limited by tomcat @Ortomala Lokni

Comment: @vigneshwaran did you find an answert to this?